# UWP app won't connect to WCF service

Tags: rest, wcf, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP tablet app that attempts to connect to a WCF service using REST hosted on a 2K8 R2 Windows Server but fails with a SocketException:

"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xx.xx.xx.xx:58993"

The application is failing at this point:

```
private String EndPoint = "xx.xx.xx.xx:58993/TabletService";
private HttpClient serviceClient = null;
serviceClient = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = serviceClient.GetAsync(new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/Initialize", EndPoint))).Result;
```

I can successfully telnet to that IP and port specified from any where on the network.

netstat -o shows the service listening on the port as expected.

Firewalls are disabled on the client and server. I have turned off AV on both machines.

The application will connect from Visual Studio (IDE) to the service installed and running on the same development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your WCF service has authentication. For example, when you call the service, you also would need to send the “account/password”. This is the first point.

The second, please check if it will work when you use browser to get this url.

The third, I suggested that you could try to change the port and open your visual studio in administrator mode, then debug your UWP app to connect to your wcf service and to see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently UWP apps are locked down and do not work across the network. They work locally when running in the IDE because Visual Studio has a builtin loopback adapter but when running across the network they need to be given specific capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest.

I added Private Network (Client & Server) capability and this solved the problem. See this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx